# How to get "Filled" theme version of Material Icons

Tags: css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui, google-material-icons

I'm using Reactjs and [Material Icons](https://material-ui.com/style/icons/#icons). [I want to get the filled version of the icon.](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline)

[But instead, I am seeing the outlined version.](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=outline)

```
import import {Icon} from '@material-ui/core';
...
<Icon>mail</Icon>
```

What am I doing wrong? And how can I get the filled version using the `<Icon>foo</Icon>` method?

Comment: I just tested this and I'm seeing the filled version

Comment: Ok. That actually helps. The problem must be somewhere upstream in my CSS then. I'm guessing.